# How to convert while loop to CTE

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression, recursive-query, cyclic-reference

We have a stored procedure in that procedure we are using a while loop, each time insert as a child of a parent any children of children. now this loop is taking more than 11 hours to complete.so can anyone help me to convert while loop to CTE? Which will reduce the execution time?  is there any other way to increase the performance of the below query? You can find the schema from the below link, if there is any issue for accessing below link please use below query.

```
CREATE TABLE Temptbl (
    ParentNumber Varchar(9) ,
    ChildNumber Varchar(9)
);

DECLARE @lastupdate INTEGER
  SET @lastupdate = 1

    WHILE (@lastupdate > 0)
BEGIN

  INSERT INTO Temptbl
  SELECT DISTINCT
         a.ParentNumber,
         b.ChildNumber
    FROM Temptbl a,
         Temptbl b
   WHERE a.ChildNumber = b.ParentNumber
     AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                       FROM Temptbl c
                      WHERE c.ParentNumber = a.ParentNumber
                        AND c.ChildNumber  = b.ChildNumber)

  SET @lastupdate = @@ROWCOUNT

END
```

[Fiddle link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/3235b/3/0)

Comment: Some sample data and expected results would help here.

Comment: Also adding some example data would also help, if we need to rewrite and verify the output..

Comment: I want to convert to same thing to CTE for improving the performance without breaking current logic

Comment: Yes, we get that, but we also need to get a clear understanding on what the code does - and more importantly, a way for us to check our solutions before posting them as answers.

Comment: It will be helpful if you can share the code,so that we can verify from our end . In while loop ,each time insert as a child of an parent any children of children

Comment: fiddle link is only useful if you provided input data with that.

Comment: I would love to help you out, but I need your help to do so. You're new here so you  should read [ask] and probably take the [tour], but most importantly, you should realize that the main goal of stackoverflow is to provide a Q & A knowledge base. This means that the question you ask now should be good enough so that future users running into a similar problem would be able to benefit from it as well.

Comment: Related - [Don't use old-style joins](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

Answer (score 0):

Try the below query. It may will help you.

```
;with cte as (
 SELECT DISTINCT
         a.ParentNumber,
         b.ChildNumber, ROW_NUMBER()over(order by a.ParentNumber) as RNO
    FROM Temptbl a,
         Temptbl b
   WHERE a.ChildNumber = b.ParentNumber
     AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                       FROM Temptbl c
                      WHERE c.ParentNumber = a.ParentNumber
                        AND c.ChildNumber  = b.ChildNumber)
)
INSERT INTO Temptbl
select ParentNumber, ChildNumber from cte
where RNO>0
```

Comment: I don't think this will handle recursive relationships A->B, B->C, C->D. Your code would add A->C but not A->D, whereas the looping nature of their original code would. I'm not sure if its an actual issue

Comment: Thank you very much James Casey and Muthamizhselvi..we will test this code with data.@james I have another question this code will reduce the execution time ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a version if you need recursion i.e. if given A->B, B->C, C->D you expect A->C and A->D

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Temptbl
CREATE TABLE Temptbl
(
    ParentNumber VARCHAR(9),
    ChildNumber VARCHAR(9)
)

INSERT INTO Temptbl (ParentNumber, ChildNumber) 
VALUES ('a1','b1'), ('b1','c1'),
       ('a2','b2'), ('b2','c2'),
       ('a3','b3'), ('b3','c1'),
       ('c1','d1');

-- expect insert of 
-- (a1, c1) via b1
-- (a1, d1) via b1 -> c1
-- (a2, c2) via b2
-- (a3, c1) via b3 
-- (a3, d1) via b3 -> c1
-- (a3, d1) via b3 -> c1
-- (b3, d1) via c1

WITH Tree(ParentNumber,ChildNumber) AS
(
    --Initialization
    SELECT ParentNumber, ChildNumber
    FROM Temptbl
        UNION ALL
    SELECT t1.ParentNumber,t2.ChildNumber AS ChildNumber
    FROM Temptbl t1
    INNER JOIN Temptbl t2 ON t1.ChildNumber = t2.ParentNumber 
        UNION ALL
    --Recursive execution 
    SELECT Tree.ParentNumber,t.ChildNumber
    FROM Temptbl t INNER JOIN Tree ON Tree.ChildNumber = t.ParentNumber 
)
INSERT INTO Temptbl
(
    ParentNumber,
    ChildNumber
)
SELECT DISTINCT
    Tree.ParentNumber,
    Tree.ChildNumber
FROM tree 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Temptbl t WHERE t.ParentNumber = tree.ParentNumber AND t.ChildNumber = tree.ChildNumber)
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 5); -- change 5 to the maximum depth of hierarchy you need it to handle

SELECT * FROM dbo.Temptbl
```

Comment: Thank you very much for sharing the code.i have tried this code and we are getting below error.  'couldnot allocate a new page for database 'TEMPDB' because of insufficient disk space in filegroup 'DEFAULT'

Comment: Either you are actually out of disk space, or the query is filling the space allocated to tempdb and tempdb is not set to autogrow. You might want to add OPTION (MAXRECURSION 5) to the end of the query to limit how deep it looks for links, which should reduce the memory the query needs.

Comment: thanks for your response, I have tried above query with the data you provided ,the output is null,can you please check that ??

Comment: I've added exactly what I mean into the code. For me the final select returns 14 rows (the 7 original plus 7 inserted rows)